# Filter json response accordingly to time stamp in kotlin

Tags: java, android, date, kotlin, calendar

Hey I have json response coming from **retrofit**. I want to **filter** accordingly to **sentAt** property. I want to compare **latest time** and move block accordingly to that. Right now in my json there is **4 items/block** but it could be more. Can some one know how to filter list and modify in efficient way. Also i need to convert **sentAt** value in **time** and **date** format and store in other variable. The format of todays date will be in **time** and if date is old i need in **date** format.

**Json Response**

```
{
  "conversations": [
    {
      "id": "789",
      "title": "Conversation Title 3",
      "lastMessage": {
        "id": "4677",
        "text": "Text 3",
        "sentAt": "2021-09-28T10:39:10.0492422+01:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "title": "Conversation Title 2",
      "lastMessage": {
        "id": "3c7e",
        "text": "Text2",
        "sentAt": "2021-09-26T12:39:10.0493518+01:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "101",
      "title": "Conversation Title 4",
      "lastMessage": {
        "id": "f983",
        "text": "Text 4",
        "sentAt": "2021-09-30T13:39:10.0493537+01:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "123",
      "title": "Conversation Title 1",
      "lastMessage": {
        "id": "f983",
        "text": "Text 1",
        "sentAt": "2021-09-26T12:38:00.0493537+01:00"
      }
    }......
  ]
}
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
  "conversations": [
    {
      "id": "101",
      "title": "Conversation Title 4",
      "lastMessage": {
        "id": "f983",
        "text": "Text 4",
        "sentAt": "2021-09-30T13:39:10.0493537+01:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "789",
      "title": "Conversation Title 3",
      "lastMessage": {
        "id": "4677",
        "text": "Text 3",
        "sentAt": "2021-09-28T10:39:10.0492422+01:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "title": "Conversation Title 2",
      "lastMessage": {
        "id": "3c7e",
        "text": "Text2",
        "sentAt": "2021-09-26T12:39:10.0493518+01:00"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "123",
      "title": "Conversation Title 1",
      "lastMessage": {
        "id": "f983",
        "text": "Text 1",
        "sentAt": "2021-09-26T12:38:00.0493537+01:00"
      }
    }......
  ]
}
```

**For example to store value in variable**

```
id : 101
time : 13:39

id : 789
time : 28/09/2021
```

**Added Data class**

**ConversationsResponse**

```
data class ConversationsResponse(
    val conversations: List<Conversations>? = null
)
```

**Conversations**

```
data class Conversations(
    val id: String? = null,
    val title: String? = null,
    val lastMessage: LastMessage? = null
)
```

**LastMessage**

```
data class LastMessage(
    val id: String? = null,
    val text: String? = null,
    val sentAt: String? = null
)
```

Comment: How are you handling this response in Java? Do you use Gson, Jackson or any other library or do you parse it *manually*? I would store the full date, time and offset using a `java.time.OffsetDateTime`, because it actually consists of a `LocalDate`, a `LocalTime` and a `ZoneOffset` and all those are separately accessible.

Comment: @deHaar I am using moshi library to parse json response. And how to filter json response ?

Comment: OK, can you show us the class(es) you are using for this?

Comment: @deHaar you mean data class ?

Comment: Yes, the data class (Kotlin) or the Pojo (Java)

Comment: @deHaar Added data class in my question. Please have a look. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example for parsing the input time and processing the date and time parts separately, for which I took one of the `sentAt`s from your JSON sample:

```kotlin
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.LocalTime
import java.time.OffsetDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

fun main() {
    // example input from JSON
    val sentAt = "2021-09-28T10:39:10.0492422+01:00"
    // parse it directly, it is in ISO standard format
    val odt: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(sentAt)
    // extract the date only
    val date: LocalDate = odt.toLocalDate()
    // extract the time of day
    val time: LocalTime = odt.toLocalTime()
    // format the date using a standard formatter
    val dateString = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    // and do the same for the time
    val timeString = time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
    // then print the formatted date and time separately
    println("date: $dateString and time: $timeString")
}
```

The output of this is

```
date: 2021-09-28 and time: 10:39:10.0492422
```

You could make use of this either directly in the `data class LastMessage` or create some utility class that converts the datetime `String`s in `LastMessage`s.

It is possible to alter the output using different `DateTimeFormatter`s. There are several built-in ones and you can create your custom formatter using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` or `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(String pattern)`. You can pass a `Locale` to a `DateTimeFormatter` if you want to control the language of named units like months, days of week.

Comment: thanks for your help. And what to filter json response is my first priority and then changing sentAt is my second priority.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime`, `LocalDate` and `LocalTime` are comparable, you could first convert the `String` to an `OffsetDateTime` and then maybe sort them. Those objects from `java.time` are handy for filtering.

Comment: i'll try to sort them

Comment: Very good answer! It is worth mentioning that The modern Date-Time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and does not require using a `DateTimeFormatter` object explicitly as long as the Date-Time string conforms to the ISO 8601 standards.